# If $A$ is negative definite, can $A$ squared be negative definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a symmetric matrix $A$ that is negative definite, then spectral decomposition theorem says that there is an orthogonal matrix $Q$(matrix of eigenvectors) such that $A=Q \Lambda Q^T$. Does that mean that $A^2$ cannot be negative definite, since $A^{2}=(Q \Lambda Q^{T})(Q \Lambda Q^{T})$ so $A^{2}=Q \Lambda ^{2} Q^{T}$ and I have the squares of eigenvalues on the diagonal, so all $A^2$ has all positive eigenvalues?

Comment: That's right. You can also see it directly: $A$ is negative definite if $v \cdot Av < 0$ for all nonzero $v$. Using the fact that $A$ is symmetric, we get $v \cdot A^2 v = Av \cdot Av \geq 0$. You can get that $Av \cdot Av > 0$ by knowing that $A$ is nonsingular, since $A$ is (negative) definite.

Comment: @Joppy You should post this as an answer so the question won't remain open forever...

Comment: @Joppy I would certainly give that answer a $+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that the square of a negative definite matrix is positive definite. You can see this by the spectral decomposition as you pointed out. It's also a general fact that the square of a symmetric matrix must be positive-semidefinite, since
$$ v \cdot A^2 v = Av \cdot Av \geq 0$$
In your case, the matrix $A$ is also (negative) definite, and hence nonsingular, so you have the strict inequality
$$ Av \cdot Av > 0$$
showing that $A$ is positive definite.